# Оптимизация сортировки PIVOT таблицы по сумме нескольких столбцов

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица score в которой хранятся набранные игроком очки:

```
+----+--------+----------------+--------------+
| id |  value |  score_type_id |   player_id  |
+----+--------+----------------+--------------+
```

Так же таблица score_type:

```
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
```

Запрос на получение суммы некоторых очков занимает довольно много времени, а в будущем будет занимать ещё больше, сам запрос:

```
SELECT 
    s.player_id,
    (SUM(CASE
        WHEN st.name = 'ffa_points' THEN value
        ELSE 0
    END) + SUM(CASE
        WHEN st.name = 'kills' THEN value
        ELSE 0
    END) + SUM(CASE
        WHEN st.name = 'teams_points' THEN value
        ELSE 0
    END) * 4) AS sumPoints
FROM
    `score` s
        JOIN
    `score_type` st ON s.score_type_id = st.id
GROUP BY s.player_id
ORDER BY sumPoints DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Как его можно оптимизировать ? Была идея создать таблицу с id игрока и суммой очков, а потом раз в час просто её обновлять, но может быть есть вариант лучше ?

Comment: индекс на `score` по `player_id` есть? а ещё лучше по `(player_id, score_type_id)`... дальше можно попробовать заменить `CASE`'ы на подзапросы (оптимизатор мог до этого не додуматься)... если всего этого будет недостаточно, то можно хранить сумму очков явно... если кроме трёх перечислленных других видов очков нет, то я бы сделал их нормальными стобцами и добавил бы вычисляемое поле... если нужна именно такая структура, то ИМХО будет лучше поддерживать когерентность общего счёта триггерами.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Все индексы стоят, просто score_type может быть скок угодно, но игрокам нужен топ, поэтому приходиться использовать сумму основных очков. Без order by данный запрос срабатывает моментально, поэтому тут надо как нибудь его оптимизировать, и опять же всё сводится к тому что придётся создавать ещё таблицу для хранения суммы, и обновлять её раз в час с помощью планировщика

Comment: вы хотя бы отфильтруйте таблицу по этим трем типам, а то считаете всю целиком.

Comment: @teran Можно поподробнее что вы имеете ввиду под отфильтровать ?

Comment: сами пишите, что у вас там много типов и данных. тащите запросом данные все целиком, а считаете только для трех. Вот тащите не все, а только по этим трем. (`st ON (.... and st.name IN ('kills', ...))`) и индекс на `name`

Comment: и просто суммируйте, других то очков не будет там. не надо никаких кейсов, вы все равно общую сумму делаете

Comment: `select player_id, sum(value) as x from score where score_type_id IN (select id from score_types where name IN (....)) group by player_id order by x desc` ведь то же самое?

Comment: а нет. не то же. на 4 умножение есть. этих коэффициентов умножения нигде не хранится? чтобы в формулу вписать?

Comment: @teran нет, не храниться, но where in ускорил запрос в 4 раза, но это временное решение, потому что со временем данных будет больше

Comment: @Spliterash, тогда похоже остаётся только последний вариант — хранить общий счёт и поддерживать его триггерами...

Comment: почему `where in` если  условие надо в `inner join` вписать?

Comment: какой вообще объем данных-то ?

Comment: @teran Пока что 100К строк, но в будущем будет больше

Answer (score 0):

как вариант:

```
SELECT s.player_id, SUM(s.value * st.k) as vsum
FROM score AS s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, 1 as k FROM score_type WHERE name IN ('ffa_points', 'kills')
    UNION 
    SELECT id, 4 as  k FROM score_type WHERE name = 'teams_points'  
) as st ON (st.id = s.score_type_id)
GROUP by player_id
ORDER BY vsum DESC
LIMIT 100
```

+индекс на `score_type_id`